# Historical Representation with graph

Tags: c#, charts, ssrs-2008

Is there any graph available which we can use for the Historical representation like below image? I just tried to mock up the Chart i want, something like this.

dont want the same graph but something which will represent the historical data.

which will display the Top 5 Item Status which are open from Past.

want to know can we achieve this with any type of chart in `SSRS` or any type of chart?

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN SSRS select the horizontal bar property. and check the reverse true and save.

Answer (score 0):

`SSRS` should have something similar or equivalent to `SeriesChartType.RangeBar` from `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`. Or perhaps you could just use this namespace as it is.

[image]

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataCollection data = new MyDataCollection();

        foreach (MyData d in data)
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(d.MyItem, new object[] { d.MyDate[0], d.MyDate[1] });

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMM";
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = data.Max(d => d.MyDate[1]).ToOADate();
    }
```

Data:

```
public class MyDataCollection : List<MyData>
{
    public MyDataCollection()
    {
        Add(new MyData { MyItem = "Item 5", MyDate = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 8, 1), new DateTime(2015, 11, 1) } });
        Add(new MyData { MyItem = "Item 4", MyDate = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 6, 1), new DateTime(2015, 11, 1) } });
        Add(new MyData { MyItem = "Item 3", MyDate = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 9, 1), new DateTime(2015, 11, 1) } });
        Add(new MyData { MyItem = "Item 2", MyDate = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 10, 1), new DateTime(2015, 11, 1) } });
        Add(new MyData { MyItem = "Item 1", MyDate = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 7, 1), new DateTime(2015, 11, 1) } });
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string MyItem { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much  "jstreet" this is great help.